Numbering an equation when using \pause and showonlyrefs
I have a tex file
\documentclass[t]{beamer}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\mathtoolsset{showonlyrefs}
\usepackage{zref-clever}
\zcsetup{cap=true}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}

We have

\begin{align}
A & = B , \label<1>{eq1}  \\
C & = D .
\end{align}

\pause

\begin{align}
E & = F ,  \\
G & = H .
\end{align}

\end{frame}

\begin{frame}

We have \eqref{eq1}.

\end{frame}

\end{document}

The numbering of A = B shows up in the first slide

However, it does not show up in the second slide


The numbering of A = B shows up in every slide that is originated from frame 1 and contains A = B.
The hyperlink \eqref{eq1} will lead to the first slide that is originated from frame 1 and contains A = B.
The hyperlink \eqref{eq1} will lead to the (last) slide where all content of frame 1 shows up.

My expacted behavior is either (1&2) or (1&3). Could you elaborate on how to solve this issue?

Well, from the discussion in the comments to your last couple of questions (Jump by \zcref is not correct with \pause, https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/732719/105447), I think you should have realized that beamer overlays (or \pause) with mathtools' showonlyrefs is a bad combination. To use @samcarter's fortunate formulation this is a situation for which showonlyrefs wasn't made for.
Formally speaking, showonlyrefs "works", but only for the slide in which it is explicitly labeled. And, no, \label{eq1} does not mean "for every slide in this frame" but is rather pretty much equivalent to \label<1>{eq1}.
That said, the "brute force" solution would be to label every slide, with something like:
\documentclass[t]{beamer}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\mathtoolsset{showonlyrefs}
\usepackage{zref-clever}
\zcsetup{cap=true}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}

We have

\begin{align}
A & = B , \label<1>{eq1-1}\label<2>{eq1-2}  \\
C & = D .
\end{align}

\pause

\begin{align}
E & = F ,  \\
G & = H .
\end{align}

\end{frame}

\begin{frame}

We have \eqref{eq1-1}\noeqref{eq1-2}.

Or \eqref{eq1-2}\noeqref{eq1-1}, if you want the link to the last slide in the
frame.

\end{frame}

\end{document}

You have full control there, but this is not only obviously inconvenient, but also error prone, since you have to treat a "set of labels" as if they were one, and you have to take care of that at every reference (or "should", in theory, at least). Let's call this "how things look like, as far as mathtools' showonlyrefs sees them".
Since you have already loaded zref-clever, you could get a bit more leeway (but not really much) using \zcref, because you could then just refer to the whole "set", and let \zcref handle things with compression to make it "just one reference".
\documentclass[t]{beamer}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\mathtoolsset{showonlyrefs}
\usepackage{zref-clever}
\zcsetup{cap=true}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}

We have

\begin{align}
A & = B , \label<1>{eq1-1}\label<2>{eq1-2}  \\
C & = D .
\end{align}

\pause

\begin{align}
E & = F ,  \\
G & = H .
\end{align}

\end{frame}

\begin{frame}

We have \zcref{eq1-1,eq1-2}.

\end{frame}

\end{document}

If you want to control the link, you can use nosort and tamper with the order of the references (when compression occurs, \zcref will point to the first).
One good suggestion by @samcarter in the discussion in the comments of your other questions was to go the "other way round: use untagged equations and add tags where needed" "(preferably with a non-numerical tag to make it better suited for presentations)". And I do think this is a good idea. It could go something like:
\documentclass[t]{beamer}
\usepackage{mathtools}
% \mathtoolsset{showonlyrefs}
\usepackage{zref-clever}
\zcsetup{cap=true}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}

We have

\begin{align*}
A & = B , \label{eq1}\tag{ABeq}  \\
C & = D .
\end{align*}

\pause

\begin{align*}
E & = F ,  \\
G & = H .
\end{align*}

\end{frame}

\begin{frame}

We have \eqref{eq1}.

\end{frame}

\end{document}

One final idea, which may be considered a sort of midway in all of this would be to enable showonlyrefs and showmanualtags, use numbered equations, set a label with a specified overlay (or not specified for the first slide), and then set manual \tags with references to that label in the remaining slides of the frame. Something like (here setting the anchor in the second slide of the frame, just to illustrate):
\documentclass[t]{beamer}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\mathtoolsset{showonlyrefs,showmanualtags}
\usepackage{zref-clever}
\zcsetup{cap=true}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}

We have

\begin{align}
A & = B , \label<2>{eq1}\only<1,3>{\tag{\ref*{eq1}}}  \\
C & = D .
\end{align}

\pause

\begin{align}
E & = F ,  \\
G & = H .
\end{align}

\pause

Blurb.

\end{frame}

\begin{frame}

We have \eqref{eq1}.

\end{frame}

\end{document}

Whatever the case may be, you need to understand, and keep in mind, that showonlyrefs sees no "frames", only "slides" and, therefore, you do need to take care of each one of them if you really want, or need, to use this hellish combination of features.

Thank you very much for your (very) detailed answer. The last solution \label<2>{eq1}\only<1,3>{\tag{\ref*{eq1}}} works great. Could you explain what is the meaning of <2> and <1,3>. I am aware that there are 2 \pause and thus 3 split slides originated from frame 1.

@Akira In beamer's terms, it is called the "overlay specification". It is usually the argument given in <>. You can think of it "slide number in a given frame". A multiple slide frame can be triggered by \pause or other mechanisms, and, given how showonlyrefs works, you need to take care of each slide. Check the beamer manual.

@Akira I think you understood it, but it is by manipulating the overlay specification there that you have the control to where the link points to. For example, to get the link to the first slide on the frame, it would be \label<1>{eq1}\only<2->{\tag{\ref*{eq1}}}, and so on.

Thank you very much for your detailed explanation.
